# Give an example of minimal homeomorphism on $\mathbb T^n$ which is homotopy to identity and not topologically conjugate to rotation map.

Tags: dynamical-systems, rotations, ergodic-theory

I know in $\mathbb T^1$ is true that if any homeomorphism is minimal then it is topological conjugate to rotation map. But In homotopy to an identity, I don't know in higher dimensional.
Any kind of help will be appreciate.

Comment: For example, the homeomorphism of two dimensional torus which sends $(x,y)$ to $(x+\alpha,y+x)$ where $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: Sorry i made mistake in question so i correct it. Please check question title again.